# vertically align div inside another div with a dynamic height

Tags: html, css

I have a html page with a page title.

The height of the page title is determined by the height of the users photograph. The users photograph can be any size.

The issue that I cannot solve myself is that I am trying to vertical-align the text title to the middle of the title holder, but I am not able to figure this out if the photo has a dynamic height (the max-height is 149px). Assigning a specific height to the div does allow the middle vertical alignment, but as the users photograph can be any height, assigning a set height can make the appearance seem odd.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

**Does someone know how to vertical align middle the users name with a dynamic height?** I have read several similar SO posts, tried several things but I cannot get this to work.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="resumeStyleNameTitleWrapper">
    <div class="resumeStyleNameTitle">
        <div class="resumeStyleNameTitleInner">
            <div class="resumeStyleNameTitleFontChange">Users Name</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="resumeStyleNameTitlePhotograph">
        <div class="resumeStyleNameTitlePhotographInner">
            {# image has max-height: 149px & max-width: 149px; assigned in the css file #}
            <img id="id_name_details_photograph" class="name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions" src="{{ name_details_photograph_url }}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.resumeStyleNameTitleWrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleNameTitle {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: calc(100% - 159px);  /*less the width of the photograph plus 10px */
    background-color: lime;
}

.resumeStyleNameTitleInner {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    max-height: 149px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
}

.resumeStyleNameTitleFontChange {
    direction: ltr;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleNameTitlePhotograph {
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    float: right;
    max-height: 149px;
    max-width: 149px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.resumeStyleNameTitlePhotographInner {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions {
    max-height: 149px;
    max-width: 149px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `max-height: 149px;` instead of a fixed height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/78Lzadtt/2/

I solved your Problem by putting **resumeStyleNameTitlePhotograph** clss in  to **resumeStyleNameTitleInner**

```
<div class="resumeStyleNameTitleWrapper">
    <div class="resumeStyleNameTitle">
        <div class="resumeStyleNameTitleInner">
            <div class="resumeStyleNameTitleFontChange">Users Name</div>
        </div>
<div class="resumeStyleNameTitlePhotograph">
        <div class="resumeStyleNameTitlePhotographInner">
            <img id="id_name_details_photograph" class="name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions" src="">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So now if your image size change then your text div will also change its height depending upon image div size

Comment: apply padding and change width of parent div

Comment: Keval Bhatt, thanks for the answer. That works great.

Answer (score 1):

## Simplify your markup

One div containing a text element and an img:

- The parent div is given `display: table` and `text-align: right` to align the image to the right
- The names element (`h2` in my example) is given `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` to keep it vertically centered. `text-align: left` brings the name to the left
- The image is given `vertical-align` to remove the default baseline gap

### Full Example

**Compatibility:** [`display: table` is recognised in IE8+ and all modern browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.name {
  background: #F00;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
.name > img {
  max-height: 149px;
  max-width: 149px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.name > h2 {
  text-align: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <h2>John Smith</h2>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200X100" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.container {
 display: table;
    width: 80%;
    background: green;
    padding: 5px;
}
.first-child {
 display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: yellow;
}
.second-child {
 display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
.text {
 color: red;
 font-size: 20px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="first-child">
  <div class="text">
   Username
  </div>
  
 </div>
 <div class="second-child">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
 </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="first-child">
  <div class="text">
   Username
  </div>
  
 </div>
 <div class="second-child">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" />
 </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="first-child">
  <div class="text">
   Username
  </div>
  
 </div>
 <div class="second-child">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will simply use table to accomplish this task. Neat and simple. No messing around with CSS, and I don't have to worry about browser compatibility.

Just ensure to set `valign` (vertical alignment) to `middle` on the column for username.

`<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="52%" valign="middle">Username</td>
        <td width="29%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="19%"><!-- IMAGE HERE --></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>`

**[HERE IS A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/07mjszbo/)**